# PHP returning extra whitespace with return statement?

Tags: php, whitespace

My code works, but for some strange reason when I return a string it adds extra space and I think a new line as well. 
The code below works fine. However the length of this when fetched with Ajax is 11, the string success has a length of seven so this isn't right and it also doesn't equal to 'success' when comparing. 
I've looked through a few other questions but all the solutions they offer don't seem to be working for me. No trailing spaces anywhere as far as I can see. And it's also not coming from any of the files I'm requiring.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Quotation Rest API
Plugin URI:  
Description: A rest API for sending quotation request through to email using Sendgrid. 
Version: 1.0
Author: Niels  
Author URI:  
*/
add_action( 'rest_api_init',  function () {
  register_rest_route( 'offerte', '/send',array(
    'methods' => 'POST',
    'callback' => 'send_mail',
  ) );
} );
include('MailChimp.php');
use \DrewM\MailChimp\MailChimp;
function send_mail( WP_REST_Request $request) {
    $data = $request['data'];
    $name = htmlspecialchars($request['name']);
    $email = htmlspecialchars($request['email']);
  $comment = htmlspecialchars($request['comment']);
  $website = htmlspecialchars($request['url']);
    $company = htmlspecialchars($request['company']);
    $tel =  htmlspecialchars($request['tel']);
    $mailchimp = htmlspecialchars($request['mailchimp']);
    $dataArray = json_decode($data, true);
  ob_start();
  include('mail.php');
  $mailHTML = ob_get_clean();
  $success = 'success'; 
  if (!empty($mailchimp)) {
// add email to mailchimp list 
    $client = new MailChimp('-us14');// get from setttings
    $list_id = ' ';// get from setttings 
    $result = $client->post("lists/$list_id/members", [
            'email_address' => $email,
            'status' => 'subscribed',
          ]);
  }
    $to = " @icloud.com";// get from setttings 
    $subject = "Offerte van " . $name;// // get from setttings  (maybe...)
    $message = $mailHTML; 
    if(wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message)){
    return $success;
  } else {
    // return 'error'; 
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Remove everytthing after `?>`. Even `?>` can be removed

Comment: @u_mulder beat me to it - you don't need `?>` because it's a php-only script

Comment: Doesn't make a difference. Thanks anyway though. Still getting a length of 11.

Comment: Try to trim the result in javascript and compare for success

Comment: But that doesn't fix the problem itself. I don't want to have a workaround.

Comment: Try to open your file in a low level text editor like MS-Dos Edit at the end , You may find some control bytes remove it and it will be fine.

Comment: I have doubt, In your AJAX you call this function directly or some other function? Because if you call another function and that function calls the above function, might be that calling function can return some additonal characters.